# Ionic 2 : using Toast inside an alert handler throws an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedException

Tags: javascript, angular, alert, ionic2, toast

I tried to **display a toast after a user pressed a button in an alert** but it **throws an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedException** in dev mode. I believe it's an ionic bug. Has anyone experienced the same issue ? Can you confirm I'm not doing any mistakes ?

Here's the code :

```
let prompt = this.alertController.create({
    title: 'Alert displaying a toast',
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel'
    }, {
      text: 'Display toast',
      handler: () => {
        displayToast();
        }
    }]
});

prompt.present();
```

and displayToast() :

```
displayToast() {
  let toast = this.toastController.create({
    message: 'toast displayed from inside an alert',
    duration: 2000
  });

  toast.present();
}
```

To reproduce the Exception, you have to display the alert multiple times and press 'cancel' or 'display' buttons many times.

Cheers

Comment: Ok looks like it's a known issue not addressed yet : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/7565